# How to extend salesforce 'send quote by email' page

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, attachment

Salesforce provide simple way to send quote by email (opportunity->quote->send email), but I need to implement another logic of sending emails: I need to send emails using API of third-party service.

I can create custom visualforce page with custom controller, but I have no idea how to include standard quote details PDF, which auto-generated by salesforce.

What the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a VF page with Quote as standard controller, and an extension class. The extension class can query all the information you need related to the quote like the related opportunity, account information, etc. Check out this link on how to convert a VF page to a PDF: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm
2. Override the *Create PDF* standard button with your VF page. In your VF page, you can replicate the functionality of the standard PDF page generated by Salesforce with buttons like "Send Email" for example.
3. You can invoke your 3rd party API to send the email using the button.

Does that help?